# Combinatorial proof for a Fibonacci identity

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs, tiling

$$f_{n+2} + f_{n-2} = 3f_n \text{ for n} \ge 1 $$

I am trying to understand the combinatorial proof that I see in the book I am reading for the above identity. Here $f_n$ represents the number of ways to tile a rectangular board of size $1 \times n$ with tiles of size $1 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$. In the book, the author establishes a 1-to-3 correspondence between the set of $1 \times n$ tilings and the set of $1 \times (n-2)$ tiling and $1 \times (n+2)$ tilings, referred to hereafter as Set 1 and Set 2 respectively, such that for every object in Set 1, we can create three unique objects in Set 2.

Set 1: Tilings of an $1 \times n$ board

Set 2: Tilings of an $1 \times (n+2)$ board or an $1 \times (n-2)$ board.

The author then explains the 1-to-3 correspondence as below:

The first tiling is an $1 \times (n+2)$ tiling created by appending a tile of size $1 \times 2$ to the $1 \times n$ tiling

The second tiling is an $1 \times (n+2)$ tiling created by appending two tiles of size $1 \times 1$ to the $1 \times n$ tiling

For the third tiling, the author comes-up with something that I can't quite wrap my head around. They say that if the $1 \times n$ tiling ends with a

i) $1 \times 2$ tile, then remove the $1 \times 2$ tiling to create a $1 \times (n-2)$ tiling.

ii) $1 \times 1$ tile, then insert a $1 \times 2$ tile before the last $1 \times 1$ tile to create a $1 \times (n+2)$ tiling.

Then, to prove the 1-to-3 correspondence, they prove that every tiling of size $1 \times (n+2)$  or size $1 \times (n-2)$ is created exactly once from some $1 \times n$ tiling. They reason it out as below:

For a given $1 \times (n+2)$ tiling, we can obtain the $1 \times n$ tiling that creates it by examining its ending and removing

i) the last $1 \times 2$ tile (if it ends with a $1 \times 2$ tile)

ii) the last two $1 \times 1$ tiles (if it ends with two $1 \times 1$ tiles)

iii) the last $1 \times 2$ tile (if it ends with a $1 \times 1$ tile preceded by a $1 \times 2$ tile)

And for a given $1 \times (n-2)$ tiling, we can simply append a tile of size $1 \times 2$ for the $1 \times n$ tiling that creates it.

And they conclude that since Set 2 is three times the size of Set 1, that the identity follows.

Although I understand all of that, I don't quite get how a tiling of size $1 \times n$ can be formed in exactly one way from a tiling of size $1 \times (n-2)$, since I could append either a tile of size $1 \times 2$ or two tilings of size $1 \times 1$ to the $1 \times (n-2)$ tiling to create an $1 \times n$ tiling.

Furthermore, I could also just as well, insert a tile of size $1 \times 1$ to a $1 \times n$ tiling, to form a $1 \times (n+1)$ tiling, if the board of $1 \times n$ ended with a tile of $1 \times 2$. Which would mean $f_{n+2} + f_{n+1} = 3f_n$. But I know this is false. I just don't know why my reasoning is incorrect.

I am sorry this one's lengthy. I would appreciate any explanations for the above two concerns.

Comment: You should mention the name of the book (*Proofs that Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not that a $1\times n$ tiling can be formed in only one way from a $1\times(n-2)$ tiling. At that point you’ve been given a very specific procedure that produces three $1\times(n+2)$ or $1\times(n-2)$ tilings from each $1\times n$ tiling, and the claim is that there is exactly one $1\times n$ tiling that could have produced any given $1\times(n-2)$ tiling **by that procedure**. The procedure produces a $1\times(n-2)$ tiling **only** by removing a $1\times 2$ tile from the end of a $1\times n$ tiling, never by removing two $1\times 1$ tiles, so the only $1\times n$ tiling from which a given $1\times(n-2)$ tiling could have resulted is the one that you get when you append a $1\times 2$ tile.

The whole second part of the argument is showing that each $1\times(n-2)$ or $1\times(n+2)$ tiling is the result of applying the procedure in the first part of the argument to a **unique** $1\times n$ tiling. That is, if you’re given a $1\times(n-2)$ or $1\times(n+2)$ tiling, you can always work backwards to discover the one and only $1\times n$ tiling that gives rise to it when you apply the procedure described in the first part of the argument. That is what shows that the procedure really does define a $1$-to-$3$ correspondence between Set $1$ and Set $2$: given a $1\times n$ tiling, there is a rule that specifies exactly $3$ corresponding members of Set $2$, and given any member of Set $2$, there is a rule that tells you the unique member of Set $1$ to which it corresponds.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I _think_ I understand your answer to the 1st part of my question. Can you explain to me why `3f_n = f_n+2 + f_n+1` is wrong? My thinking is to use the same idea as the original for making the first two tilings of 1 x n + 2 with 1 x n. For the third tiling, if 1 x n ends in a 
i) 1 x 1 tile, then append a 1 x 2 tile before the 1 x 1 tile to make a 1 x n+2 tiling
ii) 1 x 2 tiling, then append a 1 x 1 tile to make a 1 x n+1 tiling
This still looks unique to me and will make the relation I pasted here seem true. But I know it to be false. Can you explain why?

Comment: @SaileshKumar: The problem is that you don’t get all $1\times(n+1)$ tilings that way: you get only the ones that ind in a $1\times 2$ tile followed by a $1\times 1$ tile. Thus, you don’t get $f_{n+1}$ $1\times(n+1)$ tilings.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for that. The only other way of making a $1 \times (n + 1)$ tiling is to append a $1 \times 1$ tile to a $ 1 \times n$ tiling. If I include this to the above list I end up with $4f_n = f_{n+2} + f_{n+1}$ which is still not true. What am I missing?

Comment: @SaileshKumar: You get only the $1\times n$ tilings that end with a $1\times 1$ tile, and you get some of those twice — the ones that have a $1\times 2$ tile immediately before the $1\times 1$ tile. Thus, you don’t get $f_{n+1}$ tilings.

Comment: The first $1 \times (n + 1)$ is formed by appending a $1 \times 1$ tile to $1 \times n$ tiling. The second is formed when a $1 \times n$ tiling ending with a $1 \times 2$ tile is inserted with a $1 \times 1$ tile **before** the $1 \times 2$ tile. I don't think there are any tilings duplicated.

Comment: @SaileshKumar: I was going by what you actually said: you said that it was **appended**, which means that it was added at the end, not that it was inserted. If you’re inserting it before a $1\times 2$ tile, you’re still missing all of the $1\times(n+1)$ tilings that end in two $1\times 2$ tiles.

Comment: @SaileshKumar: You’re very welcome.